# Firebase Storage : How to get a download link? C#

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I have a code that should return me a download link, but it does not work, the error is that it is incorrectly written. Tell me how to get the download link from Firebase Storage correctly Firebase Storage.

вот мой код:

```
private void button28_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var task = new FirebaseStorage("*****-***.appspot.com")
        .Child("data")
        .Child("apps")
        .Child("lols").GetDownloadUrlAsync();
    MessageBox.Show(task.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Is that Flutter or JavaScript?

Comment: I use C# and the FireSharp and Firebase libraries
here is the java code as a rule:
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}

Comment: No I mean the above code.

Comment: this is a method from C# (I don't understand java)

Comment: So add #C# Tag in your Question to mean that is C# & Firebase Question(Also add Firebase Storage Tag in your Question)

Comment: okay, I'll update the post now

Comment: Add C# Tag and remove 
firebase-realtime-database
firebase-authentication If you do not have any problems with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get data, you must use async-await OR apply .then to listen for requests.

Try this approach

```
// Create a reference to the file we want to download
var starsRef = storageRef.child('images/stars.jpg');

// Get the download URL
starsRef.getDownloadURL()
.then((url) => {
  // Insert url into an <img> tag to "download"
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('err', err);
})
```

Comment: Hi, can you still tell me what libraries to connect and there is still a problem I do not quite understand how to create a file that I want to download. My libraries don't have any, I fixed it like this:

```
            // Create a reference to the file we want to download
            FirebaseStorage storageRef = new FirebaseStorage("*******.appspot.com");
            var starsRef = storageRef.Child("data/apps/file.png");
            starsRef.GetDownloadUrlAsync();

            MessageBox.Show(starsRef.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ToString());
```

Comment: @Egor What do you mean with "Libraries to Connect? Can you Clarify that?

Comment: I put it wrong, I recently started studying all this and at first I thought that you gave me the code in c# and it turned out to be java in which I unfortunately do not understand and asked to give me libraries from the code, But I already realized that this is java and right now I'm trying to solve something

Comment: @Egor But I think this is **JavaScript** not **Java**

Comment: I'm really stupid .- ., but still I will try to find the answer, I am very persistent :|I am completely stupid .-. , but still I will try to find the answer, I am a persistent student :|

Answer (score 0):

TUN TUDUN TUN TUN TUN:
Here is the answer to the question thank you: https://stackoverflow.com/users/13233657/50-seconds-of-coding

```
        private void button28_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a reference to the file we want to download
            _ = getLinkAsync();
            getLinkAsync();

        }
        public async Task getLinkAsync()
        {
            FirebaseStorage storage = new FirebaseStorage("***********.appspot.com");
            var starsRef = storage.Child("test.txt");
            string link = await starsRef.GetDownloadUrlAsync();
            MessageBox.Show(link);
        }
```