# Firebase Storage Download Url in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, firebase-storage

I am trying to download a known xml file from Firebase Storage, then parse it in the XmlReader in a C# Winforms project. But where do I get the Download Url to point the XmlReader to? I have tried the below, but it still looks for the file.xm locally.

```
new FirebaseStorage("xxxxxx.appspot.com", 
            new FirebaseStorageOptions
        {
                ThrowOnCancel = true
        })
           .Child("Documents")
           .Child("file.xml")
           .GetDownloadUrlAsync();

        var reader = XmlReader.Create("file.xml");
```

If I hardcord the downloadUrl for the file.xml on FireBase storage it acts as it sohuld.

Comment: hi, interesting, might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67358182/firebase-storage-how-to-get-a-download-link-c-sharp

Comment: The results will return a string of the xml.  So you need to use StringReader sReader = new StringReader(string).  Then use the stream in the XmlReader : XmlReader.Create(sReader)